# How to avoid duplication of html in client and server side tempates?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, templates, jquery-templates

In my experience it seems that there is a lot of duplication of html in server and client side templates. By client side I mean something like Jquery templates, and by server-side I'm mean using server-side variables with html.

In the code below the foreach loop gets executed on every page load and is used to create a list of items. Notice that it surrounds a block of html with variable placeholders that are used for dynamic values.

Below the foreach loop we have a Jquery template with the exact same html structure, the only thing that differs is the variable syntax.

Is there way to "merge" it so I don't have to repeat the same html markup structure in both cases? It just seems wrong having to use the exact same html block in both cases.

**ex**

```
   <h1>Portfolio's</h1>
            <ul id="portfolioList" class="portfolio">
                <% foreach (Portfolio p in Portfolios)
                   {  %>        
                        <li>
                            <span class="delete">[X] </span>
                            <a href="/portfolioDetails.aspx?p=<%=p.PortfolioId %>"><%=p.Name %></a>
                        </li>
                <% } %>
            </ul>

            <!-- portfolio template -->
            <script id="portfolioTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
                <li>
                    <span class="delete">[X] </span>
                    <a href="/portfolioDetails.aspx?p=${PortfolioId}">${Name}</a>
                </li>
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, your js-template is used later, to render additional portfolios, recived with AJAX?

If so, you can either - get rid of js-tmpl and return with ajax prerendered html

**-OR-**

Get rid of prerendering on serverside and use only js for this. The second is probably 'cleaner' - and if you dont want to make one more ajax request at start, you can allways render initial data into json (just like template), and only run js rendering func on it.

```
<h1>Portfolio's</h1>
<ul id="portfolioList" class="portfolio">
</ul>

<!-- portfolio template -->
<script id="portfolioTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <span class="delete">[X] </span>
        <a href="/portfolioDetails.aspx?p=${PortfolioId}">${Name}</a>
    </li>
</script>

<!-- initial rendering -->    
<script>
    (function(){
        var initData = [
          <% foreach (Portfolio p in Portfolios) { %>
            { PorfolioId : <%=p.PortfolioId%>, Name : "<%=p.Name%>" },
          <% } %>
        ];
        $("#portfolioTemplate").tmpl(initData).appendTo("#portfolioList");
    }());
</script>
```

Probably you should make some adjusments, but should work without problems.

Comment: Could you give an example on your technique for avoiding the additional ajax request for the second option?

Comment: Just remember that a bot (from google for example) probably won't see a thing since they usually do not execute javascript.

Comment: I've run into the same thing.  The solution Adam provides looks good, but the tmpl plugin is no longer being maintained.  See: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl#readme

Comment: There are dozens of JS-based template engines (like [Underscore templates](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) ), so its no problem, that jqtmpl is abandoned.

Comment: Yeah, bots may have problems with content displayed like this, but it's common problem in all AJAX based apps :/

Answer (score 0):

Using nested templates or snippets.

Comment: Could you provide some more details? I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can use hamlc. That has support for both sides...

Slim is also a good try. The client side slim is called skim.